# Editing $PATH variable for apache on mountain lion

Tags: macos, macports, apache, path

I've just installed ImageMagick using macports and am trying to use it from a php site running on Apache, but nothing I do works to add /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin to my path.

So far I've tried

- adding an export to .bash_profile (macports already did this for me)
- adding an environment variable declaration to or.apache.httpd.plist, which totally overwrites the path (using $PATH to refer to the previous path doesn't get recognised)
- redefining the PATH in /usr/sbin/envvars
- using export in /usr/sbin/envvars
- using setenv in launchd.conf
- using export in launchd.conf
- adding to the list in /etc/paths

Any ideas

Comment: Is this the standard apache/php included in OS X or did you install a MAMP distribution (and if yes, which one)? Does IM work if you specify the full path from within your PHP code or if you symlink the binaries to `/usr/bin` for testing?

Comment: It is the standard OSX apache and PHP. Symlinks was a fantastic idea and works perfectly (why doesn't macports do this for me?! I thought the whole point was that it avoids your having to muck around with stuff like this)